# Class with method that applies any function to the arguments?

Tags: python

I need a class with a mmethod that takes a function as argument and applies the function to each element of a list

```
class matrix:
    def __init__(self,xs):
        self.xs=xs  #xs is a list

    def map(self,function): ??? I don't know how to implent this one
```

The result should be something like

```
   v = matrix([1, 2, 3])
   r = v.map(sqrt)
   print(r)
   matrix [1.0, 1.41, 1.73]
```

Comment: so what's wrong with map() in general ? why do you need to write your own custom one ?

Answer (score 2):

you can call the function normally even if passed as a parameter. I would call it in a list comprehension on `self.xs`:

```
from math import sqrt

class matrix:
    def __init__(self,xs):
        self.xs=xs  #xs is a list

    def map(self,function):
        return [function(x) for x in self.xs]

v = matrix([1, 2, 3])
r = v.map(sqrt)
print(r)
```

result:

```
[1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772]
```

Not mentionning objects and classes, note that built-in `map` almost does what you require already, worth mentionning since you guessed the name in your question:

```
list(map(sqrt,[1, 2, 3]))
```

(needs to be converted to `list` since Python 3, so it's became less used than list comprehensions)

Comment: ok @leaf, I'd like to see you writing proper french at 10:30 PM :) fixed.